# React Native: How value is past by onChangeText in this TextInput code?

Tags: react-native, react-native-textinput

This code is suppose to be a generic handler function for multiple `TextInput`s, to be invoked by `onChangeText` :

```
  getHandler= key =>{
    return val =>{
      this.setState({[key]: val})
    }
  }
```

.

```
<TextInput
          onChangeText={this.getHandler('phone')}
        />
```

I don't understand where the `val` got its value, it is not defined explicitly anywhere, if val is passed by `onChangeText` and doesn't have to be explicitly named in the handler's props then why the following doesn't work without the arrow notation:

```
  getHandler = key => {
      this.setState({ [key]: val });
  };
```

also the code doesn't work without a `return`, why?

```
//this code also doesn't work without return  
getHandler = key => {
      val => {
      this.setState({ [key]: val });
    };
  };
```

Entire code [here](https://github.com/EimanKDS/EimanKDS/blob/master/AddContactForm.js)

Comment: The answer is, `onChangeText` is not passing anything to `getHandler` other than 'phone', `val` is not being passed to the handler, but `getHandler` is returning a function to `onChangeText` , so it's just like if `onChangeText`  code was like:  `<TextInput
          onChangeText={val => { this.setState({ [key] : val }) }}  />`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume that you have written the TextInput. You got your `onChangeText` function. You would call it like

```
// To avoid cases when no handler function is set
if(typeof onChangeText === "function"){ 
   onChangeText(this.value);
}
```

In your first case you are passing return value of your `getHandler` function which is this function (Unnamed):

```
val =>{
      this.setState({[key]: val})
    }
```

In other cases you are not returning a function. So when the `TextInput`'s `onChangeText` is not a function it simply ignores whatever you passed into it.

Answer (score 0):

- It's handling event binding using the higher-order function, it's one of the basic ways of writing function.